# Update table row if value match another table value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a price comparison thing, for this example let's say I have 2 tables. `products` and `cpus`.

**products** is the table of all products from all categories, it has the SKU of the product, product type, lowest price, prices from the various stores compared, links from the various stores compared, and catalog numbers from the stores compared (so I can update the price by looking at the store's catalog number).

It'd look like this (assuming i have only 1 store i'm fetching the products from):

```
+------------+------+-------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
|    SKU     | type | price | store_1_price | store_1_catalog |       store_1_link       |
+------------+------+-------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
| 20q5ekGMLw |    1 |  1064 |          1064 | YD1600BBAEBOX   | randomlink.com/linkylink |
+------------+------+-------+---------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
```

then I have a table for each product category, where I store more in-detail specs about each product.

For example, the table **cpus** (for computer processors) would have the product name, product SKU, cpu socket,frequency,TDP,cores and so on...

To visualize:

```
+------------------------------------+-------------+-------+-----------+-------+--------------+----------+
|                name                |     SKU     | price | frequency | cores | manufacturer |  socket  |
+------------------------------------+-------------+-------+-----------+-------+--------------+----------+
| i5-6600K Skylake Quad core  - Tray | 20q5ekGMLw  | 1064  |       3.5 |     4 | Intel        | LGA-1151 |
+------------------------------------+-------------+-------+-----------+-------+--------------+----------+
```

Now, I want to either `UPDATE`(if the SKU is in **products**) or `INSERT`(if `SKU` isn't in the database).

So, this is what it should look like:

```
$checkdb= $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `store_1_catalog`='".$catalog."'");
        if($checkdb->num_rows==0)
        {
        //if product not in db,add it
        }
       else{ //products in database, update it.
      //update price in 'cpus' table where the SKU is the same SKU whose catalog already exists in the 'products' table
       }
```

I already did the part where the product isn't found in the database so I have to add it. The part where I need to update the product is where i'm having the hard time, how can I update the price in the **'cpus'** table where the `SKU` is the same `SKU` whose catalog already exists in the **'products'** table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query if you have the SKU available in a variable `$sku` -

`UPDATE cpus SET price = (SELECT price from products WHERE SKU = '$sku') WHERE SKU = '$sku';`

Looking at your code, I would suggest you to do the following -

```
$checkdb = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `store_1_catalog`='".$catalog."'");

   if($checkdb->num_rows==0)
    {
         //if product not in db,add it
    }
   else{
      //products in database, update it.
      //update price in 'cpus' table where the SKU is the same SKU whose catalog already exists in the 'products' table

      $row = $checkdb->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $sku = $row["SKU"];
      $conn->query("UPDATE cpus SET price = (SELECT price from products WHERE SKU = '$sku') WHERE SKU = '$sku'");
   }
```

Please note the code may break, for it is not tested. If it does, I'll promptly update with tested code.

Comment: I don't have the variable but your comment helped me figuring it out, I managed to make it work. thanks